# What are some precautions to consider when using HMIs?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting

What are the dos and don'ts of using HMI lights?

For example, I've heard you're not supposed to "hot strike" them.

Is there anything else I should know about?

Comment: If anyone else wonders what HMI is: it's a kind of arc light. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrargyrum_medium-arc_iodide_lamp ... "HMI lamps have been known to explode violently at the end of their lifetime or if stressed enough".

Comment: @che: thanks, i was just wondering exactly that...

Comment: This question is really kind of vague. Sean, could you be more specific about your concerns? What are you doing? Is this for a photography project or is it for film?

Comment: Specifically with regard to the bounty: HMIs had a brief "glory period" back in the late '80s and early '90s for stills. They were a cool, daylight-balanced alternative for halogens in the days when full-spectrum, high-frequency fluorescents simply didn't exist, entry-level studio flashes were *horrible* and expensive, and speedlights were impractical. Only a few of us old coots are likely to have had any experience with them, and we were used to the thermal properties of high-wattage halogens (which are very similar as far as handling and heat cycling go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only answer would be to follow the safety guidelines found at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrargyrum_medium-arc_iodide_lamp#Safety):

> HMI lamps can reach ignition voltages
>   of up to 70,000 V when striking hot,
>   and are considered very dangerous if
>   miswired. It is good practice to
>   strike the light from the ballast and
>   not the head, in the event that there
>   is a short circuit in the lamp head.
>   Proper striking procedures should be
>   followed as well, such as calling out
>   a vocal warning whenever a light is
>   turned on to warn persons in the area.
>   Also, the header cable should be
>   properly and securely connected (most
>   header cables will twist and click
>   into place).
>
> In addition to these concerns, HMI
>   lamps have been known to explode
>   violently at the end of their lifetime
>   or if stressed enough. While not as
>   violent as the explosion of a xenon
>   short-arc bulb, they still require
>   caution. As a result, HMI lamps should
>   not be used past half their rated
>   lifetime, and care should be taken
>   with larger lamps when striking
>   (turning on the lamp), as a lamp is
>   most likely to explode within the
>   first five minutes of striking. Care
>   should also be taken transporting the
>   lamp and replacing lamps. The gasses
>   in an HMI lamp are under pressure,
>   which increases with temperature.
>   Dropping the lamp could result in an
>   explosion, sending hot quartz glass
>   flying. As with quartz-halogen bulbs,
>   care should be taken not to touch the
>   glass directly as skin oils can
>   attract heat and cause a weak point on
>   the bulb. Most lamp housing designs
>   are inherently tougher and thicker
>   than traditional tungsten units so
>   that in the event of a bulb explosion,
>   those nearby are protected from flying
>   debris. There is the possibility of
>   the front lens element on the lamp
>   head cracking from thermal shock.
>   Proper safety procedures should be
>   followed when using HMI units, as they
>   can be quite dangerous if misused.

Comment: This copy/pasted Wikipedia excerpt is a decent answer. The reason I created the bounty, though, is to encourage someone to write a well-written, canonical answer within Stack Exchange.